# what is the best lucene setup for ranking exact matches as the highest

Tags: java, lucene, analyzer

Which analyzers should be used for indexing and for searching when I want an exact match to rank higher then a "partial" match? Possibly set up custom scoring in a `Similarity` class?

For example, when my index consist of `car parts`, `car`, and `car shop` (indexed with `StandardAnalyzer` on lucene 3.5), a query for `"car"` results in:

- car parts
- car
- car shop

(basically returned in the order in which they were added, since they all get the same score).

What I would like to see is `car` ranked first, then the other results (doesn't really matter which order, I assume the analyzer can influence that).

Answer (score 2):

All three matches are *exact* (term car being matched, not 'ca' or 'ar') :)

If there's no more content in these fields ("car parts", "car" and "car shop"), then you could use `lengthNorm()` or `computeNorm()` (depending on Lucene version), to give shorter fields more weight so that car gets higher score for being shorter. In Lucene 3.3.0, DefaultSimilarity.computeNorm() looks like this:

```
return state.getBoost() * ((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)));
```

where `numTerms` is the total number of terms in the field. So it's surprising "car" and "car shop" documents have the same score, because for "car" the norm is 1 and for "car shop" it should be 0.7 (assuming boost of 1).

Comment: Lucene 3.5 here. It could be that the scores mentioned were based on a custom similarity class, trying to get better results. Still indexed on the StandardAnalyzer though, any comments on that?

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack: after getting the `ScoreDoc[]` from `IndexSearcher.search`, re-sort it with `score` as the first criterion and length (ascending) as the second.

Comment: That might leave out (possible) better matching results when searching with the `search(query,limit)` method?

Comment: @NoMoreMrCodeGuy: yes, it might.