# Why Lucene does not return the results based on whole word match?

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I am using Lucene to match the keywords with list of words within an application. The whole process is automated without any human intervention. Best matched result (the one on the top and highest score) is picked from the results list returned from Lucene.

The following code demonstrates the above functionality and the results are printed on  console.

**Problem :**

The problem is that lucene searches the keyword (word to be searched) and gives as a result a word that partially matches the keyword. On the other hand the full matched result also exists and does not get ranked in the first position.

For example, if I have lucene RAM index that contains words 'Test' and 'Test Engineer'. If i want to search index for 'AB4_Test Eng_AA0XY11' then results would be

Test 
 Test Engineer

Although Eng in 'AB4_Test Eng_AA0XY11'  matched for Engineer (that is why it is listed in results). But it does not get the top position. I want to optimize  my solution to bring the 'Test Engineer' on top because it the best match that considers whole keyword. Can any one help me in solving this problem?

```
public class LuceneTest {

private static void search(Set<String> keywords) {

    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
    try {
        // 1. create the index
        Directory luceneIndex = buildLuceneIndex(analyzer);

        int hitsPerPage = 5;
        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(luceneIndex);

        for(String keyword : keywords) {

            // Create query string. replace all underscore, hyphen, comma, ( , ), {, }, . with plus sign
            StringBuilder querystr = new StringBuilder(128);
            String [] splitName = keyword.split("[\\-_,/(){}:. ]");

            // After tokenizing also add plus sign between each camel case word. 
            for (String token : splitName) {
                querystr.append(token + "+");
            }

            // 3. search
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
            TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);

            Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "name", analyzer).parse(querystr.toString());
            searcher.search(q, collector);
            ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(keyword);
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits) {
                Document d = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
                System.out.println("Found " + d.get("id") +  " : " + d.get("name"));
            }

            // searcher can only be closed when there
            searcher.close();
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
private static Directory buildLuceneIndex(Analyzer analyzer) throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException{

    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, "Test Engineer");
    map.put(2, "Test");

    Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);

    // 1. create the index
    IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        try {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new Field("id", entry.getKey().toString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.add(new Field("name", entry.getValue() , Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            w.addDocument(doc);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    w.close();

    return index;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<String> list = new TreeSet<String>();

    list.add("AB4_Test Eng_AA0XY11");
    list.add("AB4_Test Engineer_AA0XY11");

    search(list);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [Lucene Query syntax rules](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html) to see how you can enforce the search for `Test Engineer`.

Basically, using a query such as

```
 AB4_Test AND Eng_AA0XY11
```

*could* work, though I am not sure of it. The page pointed by the link above is quite concise and you will be able to find rapidly a query that can fulfill your needs.

Comment: Thanks. It is general  help that i already have read and tried out but could not get my desired results.Can you guide me some tips specific tips/ solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If these two results (test , test engineer) have the same ranking score, then you will see them in the order they came up.
You should try using the length filter and also boosting of the terms, and maybe then you can come  up with the solution.

See also:
[what is the best lucene setup for ranking exact matches as the highest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786343/what-is-the-best-lucene-setup-for-ranking-exact-matches-as-the-highest?rq=1)